# PreserveIds using inheritance id db auto incrementing

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am working on this project where I like to PreserveIds once inserted into the database. The id are auto incrementing and I return them once the data in inserted. I like to know if there is a better way using inheritance vs using a for each loop and checking if the value is 0?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var States = new List<StatesModel>();
            var CaliforniaCity = new List<CityModel>();
            CaliforniaCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 2, Name = "Los Angeles" });
            CaliforniaCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 3, Name = "Sacramento" });
            CaliforniaCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 4, Name = "San Francisco" });
            States.Add(new StatesModel() { Id = 1, Name = "California", CityModels = CaliforniaCity });

            var PhiladelphiaCity = new List<CityModel>();
            PhiladelphiaCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 5, Name = "Philadelphia" });
            PhiladelphiaCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 6, Name = "Pittsburgh" });
            PhiladelphiaCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 7, Name = "Harrisburg" });
            States.Add(new StatesModel() { Id = 8, Name = "Pennsylvania", CityModels = PhiladelphiaCity });

            var MichiganCity = new List<CityModel>();
            MichiganCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 9, Name = "Detroit" });
            MichiganCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 10, Name = "Lansing" });
            MichiganCity.Add(new CityModel() { Id = 11, Name = "Grand Rapids" });
            States.Add(new StatesModel() { Id = 12, Name = "Michigan", CityModels = MichiganCity });

///Insert Data in database

            PreserveIds(States)

///Update data in database 


            foreach (var State in States)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", State.Name));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", State.Id ,State.OriginaId));
                foreach (var city in State.CityModels)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", city.Name));
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", city.Id, city.OriginaId));
                }
            }


        }


        public static void PreserveIds(IEnumerable<StatesModel> States)
        {
            if (States != null)
            {
                foreach (var State in States)
                {
                    if (State.OriginaId == 0)
                    {
                        State.OriginaId = State.Id;
                    }

                    foreach (var city in State.CityModels)
                    {
                        if (city.OriginaId == 0)
                        {
                            city.OriginaId = city.Id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Model

    public class StatesModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OriginaId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<CityModel> CityModels { get; set; }
        public StatesModel()
        {
            CityModels = new List<CityModel>();
        }
    }


    public class CityModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OriginaId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I've got the feeling this is a "Your Princess is in Another Castle" problem. As in: you want to do something, but you cannot express what or why. What is the point of `OriginaId`? Why do you need to store this ID? Why do you use the old `String.Format`? Why don't you use "modern" initializers ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers )? To me, this question is far too vague.

Comment: id is a database auto incrementing number which i get once I save the data into the database. But I also want that id to be inserted into the OriginaId field. there will be iterations of inserts and I will need a pointer to the original id from the first insert.

Comment: I still can't make heads or tails of it. Why would you insert the same info again into another record? And what good would it do to have the ID of the first record stored into another record? Based on your example I don't even see the need for multiple inserts: things like cities and states don't just randomly change from day to day. Why would you have multiple records of Detroit for instance?

Answer (score 1):

I would change implementation if `Id` property in both your models into:

```
public class StatesModel
{
    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;

            if (OriginalId == 0)
                OriginalId = value;
        }
    }

    public int OriginalId { get; private set; }

    // (...)
}

// The same for CityModel
```

and remove your `PreserveIds` method all together. You can also add private setter to `OriginalId` just to make sure that nobody would override this value.

Comment: Can I do this if I am getting the Id from the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework, then you don't need to. Whenever you `SaveChanges()` it'll automatically update the current object with the auto generated id from the database.

so the basic usage would be for instance like this :

```
var california = new StatesModel() { Name = "California", CityModels = CaliforniaCity };
Console.WriteLine($"Id: {california.Id}"); // here will be zero 
context.States.Add(california); 
context.SaveChanges();      
Console.WriteLine($"Id: {california.Id}"); // the new updated Id
```

[read more](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/how-to-get-id-of-saved-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx) about it

Comment: Right that part understand but that about the update for the OriginalId? I will need the id returned from the database then sql for the update ? I am using Linqtosql

Comment: @Jefferson in Linq To SQL, `context.SubmitChanges();` does the same. What's the purpose of the `OriginalId` ? as you already have `Id` ..

Comment: I will different iterations of inserts and I will need a pointer to the original id from the First insert

Comment: @Jefferson if your `original id` is a reference to another `Id` that has been already inserted, then why not using foreign key (self-reference). ?

Comment: But this would be the same table. I was thinking a FOREIGN KEY is a field in one table that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.

Comment: @Jefferson yes, that is true also. you can reference a PK column in the same table or a different table. so your case is called (self-reference) where the FK is referencing the same table's PK.

Comment: How would I do that with linq to sql?

Comment: @Jefferson probably you need to read this  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39104/LINQ-to-SQL-Many-to-Many-Relationships

Comment: is that the same thing? there is three table in that example I am just working with one table?